# Trying to understand how to make a program do three things with a button press

Tags: arduino-uno

I am trying to write some code, which I barely grasp - but it's coming along! But I think I've hit a wall that I could using some help getting  over...

I'm not asking for you to fix my code - I know that's not how I am going to learn, maybe explain why my code isn't doing what I want it to, and/or some resources I can using to learn about it.

I think it has something to do with me trying to use the same pins in the initialization part since the error is about a conflicting declaration..

Here's my breadboard layout if this helps too:

[image: My breadboard]

```
//ABOUT - This programs goal is to make a button cycle through three    different 'modes'
//Mode 1 - make a RGB LED cycle through its colors
//Mode 2 - make the same RGB LED fade-cycle through its colors
//Mode 3 - make the same RGB LED blink on-off all three colors at once
//Additional modes may follow but this is the beginning.

//currently all my initialization code is from three different programs and I think that's why parts are not working.. I think
//I can share the mode initialization code for each mode....?  But the face code uses the uint8_t vs just int so maybe not?

//Button Cycle - this is the first part of my code, designed to teacah me how to make a button cycle through to different parts of the code

int counter = 0;
int switchPin = 13;
int LEDB = 11;
int LEDG = 10;
int LEDR = 9;

//RGB LED Cycle Circuit - mode 1
const int redLED=3; //red LED connects to digital pin 8
const int blueLED=5; //blue LED connected to digital pin 7
const int greenLED=6; //green LED connected to dogotal pin 6

//RGB LED Fade Circuit - mode 2
const uint8_t redLED = 3;  // pin connected to the red LED - I don't understand why this code says const uint8_t  -  
const uint8_t blueLED = 5;  // pin connected to the green LED
const uint8_t greenLED = 6; // pin connected to the yellow LED

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600); //I added this to help learn what the counter was doing
  pinMode(switchPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(LEDR, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LEDG, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LEDB, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  //Handle input
  int switchVal = digitalRead(switchPin);
  if(switchVal == LOW) //changed from HIGH which was making the modes appear to change randomly - may come in useful later but not what I want initially
  {
    delay(500);  
    counter ++;
    Serial.println(counter); //prints value of counter to serial monitor so I can see why it appeared to be random
    //I learned that when the switchVal == HIGH was in place the counter would cycle continuously. Making each button
    //press appear random. Changing this to LOW made the counter wait for a LOW event before counting. Increasing the 
    //delay to half a sec gives time to release the button before the counter continues.

    //Reset count if over max mode number
    if(counter > 3)
    {
      counter = 1; //in serial monitor you will see that the counter goes to 4 but this code tells the program that 4 = 1 so it runs the right mode
    }
  }
  else
    //Change mode 1
    switch (counter) {
    case 1:
      analogWrite(LEDB, 000);
      analogWrite(LEDG, 000);
      analogWrite(LEDR, 255);

      //start LED Cycle - this is simply pasted in from the LED cycle program - seems to work fine

      digitalWrite(redLED,HIGH);//turns the LED on
      delay(100);//waits 3 seconds
      digitalWrite(redLED,LOW);//turns the LED off
      digitalWrite(greenLED,HIGH);//turns the LED on
      delay(100);//waits 3 seconds
      digitalWrite(greenLED,LOW);//turns the LED off
      digitalWrite(blueLED,HIGH);//turns the LED on
      delay(100);//waits 3 seconds
      digitalWrite(blueLED,LOW);//turns the LED off
      break;

    //mode 2 code
    case 2:
      analogWrite(LEDR, 000);
      analogWrite(LEDB, 000);
      analogWrite(LEDG, 255);

      //LED Fade Cycle
      // Fade an analog pin up and down.
      void fade(uint8_t pin);
      {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 255; i=i+5) {
          delay(10);  
        }
        for (int i = 254; i >= 0; i=i-5) {              
          delay(10);
        }     
      }
      //void loop(); - think I can only have one void loop so I'm commenting this out for now..
      {
        //Serial.println(F("Fading GREEN."));
        fade(redLED);
        //Serial.println(F("Fading BLUE."));
        fade(blueLED);
        //Serial.println(F("Fading YELLOW."));
        fade(greenLED);
      }
      break;

    //mode 3 not coded yet - waiting to make mode 2 work
    case 3:
      analogWrite(LEDG, 000);
      analogWrite(LEDR, 000);
      analogWrite(LEDB, 255);
      break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Change the title to a more specific question.  What exactly about the code do you not understand?

Answer (score 2):

There are two immediate things I can see wrong:

1. You have two sets of the same pin definitions. You only want one set. Both sets are identical - once it's defined its defined - you can't define it again as the same thing.
2. You seem to have a function defined in the middle of your loop() function.  That can't work - functions have to be separate things. (also you don't want a `;` in your function definition...)

Answer (score 0):

You've used the blue lower rail for Ground but used the red lower rail (usually used for +5v) as a simple connection point. It's not wrong but it's unusual enough to be confusing to readers. The choice of red  button-signal wire on the red rail also strongly suggest a connection to +5v even though that is not the case here.

The buttons, "tact" switches, are confusing by design (see picture below). Each pair of pins curved toward each other (I marked one with a red arrow) are the physically *same* pin and always connected to each other. The *pairs* are connected to each other only when the button is pressed. It's really easy to miss that and insert the button 90deg either way from what you intended. Fritzing's button icon doesn't show the orientation either. Yours may well be correct - it's just a pitfall to be aware of.

[image: Typical "Tact" switch]

`void fade(uint8_t pin);` doesn't define a function - it declares that one exists somewhere else. I think you meant `void fade(uint8_t pin){ ... }` (note no semi-colon), which would define the function, if that were a proper location to do so. But in C and C++, functions may not be defined within other functions (loop(), in this case). Fix the definition of 'fade' and move it to above 'setup()'. That will properly define it and make it usable from within the loop() function.

The braces, {}, where you tried to define a second loop function are unnecessary (and, you're correct, you can't define more than one function with the same name and signature (parameter count & types, and return type). But you don't need another `loop()`; the code contained in the {} - three calls to the fade function - remain part of `case 2:`.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are missing is a pulldown resistor for the button. Simply put, a pulldown resistor is a resistor pulls down the input reading to 0 when the button is not pressed. Without the pulldown resistor, the value read in the `digitalRead` will float around giving inaccurate results.

[image]

Above is a circuit showing how the pulldown resistor should be wired with a button.

If you would like to learn more about pulldown resistors, please refer to [this page describing buttons in the Arduino Website](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Button).

This is just a hardware issue I noticed; hopefully, this will help you out in addition to the other recommendations given.

As a side note, a pull-up resistor can also be used, and in this case, the value will be 1 when the button is not pressed.